# Cannot add type hint to abstract's subclass method python

Tags: python, abstract-class, type-hinting

I'm trying to add type hint for abstract's subclass method:

```py
class A(ABC, Dataset):
    def __init__(self, raw_data: pd.DataFrame, pipeline: Union[Pipeline,Iterable,Dict])

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, raw_data: pd.DataFrame, pipeline: Union[Pipeline,Iterable,Dict])
```

I've got an error that refer to class B `init` method:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: This looks more like you are trying to index some object `ABCMeta` (are you defining this later on?) rather than an issue with type hinting. Your type hinting looks fine.

Comment: @tania thanks for your comment, am I defining what?

Comment: I meant: what is `ABCMeta`? It doesn't appear in the code you pasted.

Comment: Oh, no this was mentioned only in the error message..

Comment: Elik, this happens when you have types imported from `collections` instead of `typing`. Check if you have anything like that.

Comment: @MarioIshac thanks Mario! Indeed I've imported from `collection` by mistake, I need to change it to `typing`